# How does one pronounce the following cyrillic letters in their respective languages?

Tags: ipa

ӯ - Tajik

ҷ - Tajik

ӣ - Tajik

ҳ - Tajik

х - Tajik

ғ - Kazakh

And what is the difference between қ and к in Kazakh?
I would prefer an answer that doesn't refer to the IPA. For example, I know that ғ refers to the voiced uvular fricative ʁ, but this tells me nothing about the sound it makes.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want IPA I do not see how we are supposed to answer your question.

Comment: @fdb By actually describing the sounds? It sounds like the asker doesn't know what "voiced uvular fricative" means.

Comment: It's not the purpose of this site to replicate information easily available in phonetics textbooks or Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First letter   ӯ or Ӯ(capital) - always sounds like u in ('burn')
- Second letter  ҷ or Ҷ - is same as English "J"
- Third letter   ӣ or Ӣ - like y in "crazy", but be careful this letter always comes at the end of the word and there is one more letter "й" which might be used in the middle of word.
- Fourth letter  ҳ or Ҳ - same as English "H"
- Fifth letter   x or X - this one sounds slightly different from English letters, this would sound more like combination of "k" and "h" ="kh", actually even while Tajiks are using Latin alphabet for this X they probably type "KH".
- And there is also ғ or Ғ in Tajik, if you have heard how does the French pronounce "R" the Tajik Ғ sounds the same. It is like combination of "G" and "H"-"Ghe" but more likely pronounced with a small gargle
  Good luck for learning Tajik

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to the [Tajik examples on Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/languages-pronunciations/tg/), so that you can "experience" <Ӯ>. Be warned that many of the recordings are crappy, and the volume-swings from token to token can break your eardrums. [This guy](http://www.forvo.com/user/ibrahimjon/) made some reasonable recordings. You can get Kazakh [here](http://www.forvo.com/languages/kk/).